# If $f\in \mathcal{C}_0 (K)$, then $M_f =\{ t\in K \; :\; |f(t)|=\| f\|\}$ is nonempty and compact.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a locally compact topological space. As usual, $\mathcal{C}(K)$ denotes the space of all real continuous mappings defined on $K$, endowed with the supremum norm and
$$\mathcal{C}_0 (K)=\{ f\in \mathcal{C}(K)\; :\; \forall \varepsilon >0, \; \text{the set}\; \{ t\in K\; :\;  |f(t)|\geq \varepsilon \} \; \text{is compact} \} .$$

If $f\in \mathcal{C}_0 (K)$, then why $M_f =\{ t\in K \; :\; |f(t)|=\| f\|\}$ is nonempty and compact?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false. Take $f=0$. Then $M_f = K$ is only compact when $K$ is. So for example, $K= \mathbb{R}$ gives a counterexample.

If $f\ne 0$, it is true. Indeed, consider a value $t_0 \in K$ with $\epsilon:=|f(t_0)| > 0$. Then there is a compact subset $L$ with
$$t \notin L \implies |f(t)| < \epsilon.$$

Then note that $\|f\|_\infty= \sup_{t\in L} |f(t)|$ and by continuity and compactness the supremum is actually a maximum, i.e. there exists $t\in L$ with $|f(t)|= \|f\|_\infty$. Hence, $M_f \ne \emptyset.$

To see that $M_f$ is compact, choose a compact subset $L$ such that
$$t\notin L\implies |f(t)| < \|f\|_\infty.$$
Then we see that
$$M_f= \{t \in K: |f(t)| = \|f\|_\infty\}\subseteq L.$$
Since $L$ is compact and $M_f$ is closed, $M_f$ is compact as well.

Comment: Dear @QuantumSpace ,thank you very much for your nice answer. Sorry, I have a question. Why $M_f$ is nonempty?

Comment: @M.Ramana I prove this in my answer. Is something still unclear?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see it. No, nothing. I appreciate for your help.